# Indexing of spark inmemory table

Tags: apache-spark

I have registered a temp table in spark and cached that table in memory. I query a lot on this table on a particular column i.e. range query, that is a timestamp. The records are around 4 million and it takes around 25 sec to filter records on the range column. I do it around 50 times to get records between times. Is there a way wherein i can have a btree index on this column so that my queries are much faster

Answer (score 1):

Write the filter so it would get all the relevant records in one go (filter(x=> x.field>= date1 && x.field <= date2)

Comment: yes, I use a filter to filter out records. I have records from x time to y time. I need to divide the time into 1 hour slot each and take records in this one hour to process. So I get the min and max time from the records and iterate to have one hour records using filter. This filter takes around 20-30 seconds

Comment: Also all my table is in memory on one slave. Is there a way to split the records into multiple slaves so that I can filter out records in a much faster way?

Comment: "Also all my table is in memory on one slave @Nipun how to arrive to this conclusion. This can happen if you onle one partition. You can always re-partition the RDD

Comment: please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775696/repartitioning-of-dataframe-in-spark-does-not-work?noredirect=1#comment53390935_32775696